# oAuth using SwiftyJSON to read the results?

Tags: json, api, swift, oauth, swifty-json

I am creating an application that uses an API, for the sake of example, lets just say the Twitter API because it is one that most people are familiar with and it does't really matter for this which API is used and where the JSON results are coming from.

So using an none secured API, I can just run the following code:

```
let urlPath = "http://mySimpleApi.com/results.js"
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
        println(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    var err: NSError?
    var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
    if err != nil {
        // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
        println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
    }

    let json = JSON(jsonResult)




    let userName:JSON = json["user"]["name"]
    let userNameString = userName.string!
    println(userNameString)



})
task.resume()
```

The results are returned in a JSON format and the program code above successfully prints out the results users name. Maybe I should quickly show you the format of the JSON just so you know what your looking at.

```
{
  "user" : 
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "login": "bob2006",
    "password": "bobsEncryptedPassword",
  }  
}
```

So when the following code was run I was returned with the name "Bob" in the console; exactly what I expected to happen.

So obviously this is quit simple and I was just doing this to explore and experiment with JSON and ways to make it work with my apps.

So my issue here is when I want to use a oAuth API like Twitters. If I just send an unauthenticated request, I get the expected:

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

Now what I expected to happen was when I changed my original code and put the link that gave me this error was that I could specify `let userName:JSON = json["errors"][0]` to select the firs item in the `errors` area. I am just assuming this is an array because it used square brackets to open up. When this didn't work I tried `let userName:JSON = json["errors"][0][message]` instead but this didn't work, I got the same error. The error highlights the code and says:

```
Thread 3: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
```

Then in the console this is returned:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

The reason I care so much about this not working is more to understand why it isn't so I know when I am playing this to practical situations - obviously getting the error message out of the twitter API probably doesn't have a very big practical application.

Finally, I just wanted to say that when I do send an authenticated request though by browser, the file is downloaded and not displayed on the browser like the other JSON files I have been using are. Does this make a difference when applying it to an application or does it work exactly the same and I just have to work with it the same as any other JSON format?

I know this was a long question but I think I have included all the relevant information.

Please be patient with me - I am just learning, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
let userName: JSON = json["user"]["name"]
let userNameString = userName.string!
println(userNameString)
```

with

```
let dic = json["errors"][0]
let code = dic["code"].int
println(code!)

let msg = dic["message"].string
println(msg!)
```

for your second example.